# Spring Security session timeout is too short

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-mvc, spring-security

I don't know how, but session timeout is incredibly short. As I know Spring Security session timeout depends on default server's session configurations. I've found out that GlassFish timeout is 1800 sec(10 min). But I think session removes every 5 minutes. How could this happened?
This is my Spring Security configurations:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">    



    <!-- enable use-expressions -->
    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">

        <intercept-url pattern="/adminRole/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />

        <intercept-url pattern="/userRole/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />

        <!-- access denied page -->
        <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />

        <form-login 
            login-page="/" 
            default-target-url="/resolveRoles" 
            authentication-failure-url="/?error" 
            username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password" />
            <remember-me key="key" token-validity-seconds="2419200" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/?logout"  />
        <!-- enable csrf protection -->

    </http>



    <!-- Select users and user_roles from database -->
    <authentication-manager>
      <authentication-provider>
      <password-encoder hash="sha"/>      
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
          users-by-username-query=
            "select username,password, enabled from smsc.users where username=?"
          authorities-by-username-query=
            "select username, role from smsc.user_roles where username =?  " />
      </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

Comment: As you already stated yourself, session timeout is bound to the server not Spring Security. On tomcat (and afaik also on glassfish) this is 30 minutes (not 10 minutes). If this is different then you have either changed the default or you have reconfigured it in your web.xml.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is only the session timeout, but no additional timeout in spring security (except the one for the remember me token, but this is a different thing).

You can configure the session timeout within the `web.xml`:

```
<web-app>
   <session-config>
      <!-- in minutes -->
      <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
   </session-config>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Ralph, I've tried changing this to 1 minutes but doesn't seem to change it... I'm using Grails.

Comment: @Alexander Suraphel: does your web application poll the server?

Comment: No it doesn't. It times out when it's set to 30 mins though. Is there some lower bound?